# Android libraries for Previewing Office document file formats

Tags: android, library, document-converter, documentation-viewer, file-preview

I'm looking for a library that I can use to preview `doc`, `docx`, `xls`, `xlsx`, `ppt`, `pptx` etc. file formats inside my Android application. Using intents is unsuitable for my particular application and it has to be displayed in app. A few questions from 5 or so years ago deal with this question, but there does not seem to be any free / open-source answer available. All I want is for it to be displayed to the user (if the software converts the documents to pdf and displays them, I would not mind that either)

So far, The solutions i have seen are either paid, or very primitive. Are there any new reccomendations that are available, other than the ones mentioned in [This old post](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14378/android-libraries-for-rendering-common-document-file-formats)?